# Scala Parser Combinators: how to define a line

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to get my thick head around the following problem:

```
class LineParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
   def lines: Parser[Any] = rep(line)
   def line: Parser[String] = """^.+$""".r

}

object LineParserTest extends LineParser {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val reader = new FileReader(args(0))
       println("input : "+ args(0))
       println(parseAll(lines, reader))
   }
}
```

Input file:

```
one
two
```

When I run the program, it gives me this error:

```
[1.1] failure: string matching regex `^.+$' expected but `o' found

one

^
```

Apparently, I did something stupid, but couldn't figure out why. Please advise.

The above is a simplified version of the real goal: to parse a cisco-like configuration file which include commands and sub-commands and build an AST. There are several commands that I don't care and would like to ignore them using the pattern """^.+$""" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `^` and `$` in the regex. By default `.` doesn't match end of line, so the following will make it work:

```
def line: Parser[String] = """.+""".r
```

In Java, if you want `^` and `$` to match the line terminator, you have to set the [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) flag. So the following definition will work as well:

```
def line: Parser[String] = """(?m)^.+$""".r
```